# Data Structure for Segue?

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures, uiviewcontroller, segue

In iOS application which is the most optimized Data Structure being used for the the navigation among View Controllers and how do they work actually?

Example: In the given image 'VC.JPEG', at top we have navigation controller and forward and backward arrows are taking to next and previous screens respectively. Now at bottom of every screens,(namely A, B, C & D)we have Btn1, Btn2 and so on. When we click Btn1 it takes us from A to B, for Btn2 from B to C, for Btn3 from C to D and finally for Btn4 from D to A. So which Data structure should be best fitted for it with no extra memory requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the profile shown is yours and disable follow button...